# Haskell - format issue

Tags: haskell, format

i am a beginner in haskell programming and very often i get the error

```
xxx.hs:30:1: parse error on input `xxx'
```

And often there is a little bit playing with the format the solution. Its the same code and it looks the same, but after playing around, the error is gone.

At the moment I've got the error

```
LookupAll.hs:30:1: parse error on input `lookupAll'
```

After that code:

```
lookupOne :: Int -> [(Int,a)] -> [a]
lookupOne _ [] = []
lookupOne x list = 
    if fst(head list) == x then snd(head list) : []
    lookupOne x (tail list)
-- | Given a list of keys and a list of pairs of key and value
--   'lookupAll' looks up the list of associated values for each key
--   and concatenates the results. 

lookupAll :: [Int] -> [(Int,a)] -> [a]
lookupAll [] _ = []
lookupAll _ [] = []
lookupAll xs list = lookupOne h list ++ lookupAll t list    
    where
        h = head xs
        t = tail xs
```

But I have done everything right in my opinion. There are no tabs or something like that. Always 4 spaces. Is there a general solutoin for this problems? I am using notepad++ at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: You forget that `else` clause is not an optional part of an `if` expression in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `lookupAll`, it's actually with the previous two lines of code

```
if fst (head list) == x then snd (head list) : []
lookupOne x (tail list)
```

You haven't included an `else` on this if statement.  My guess is that you meant

```
if fst (head list) == x then snd (head list) : []
else lookupOne x (tail list)
```

Which I personally would prefer to format as

```
if fst (head list) == x
    then snd (head list) : []
    else lookupOne x (tail list)
```

but that's a matter of taste.

---

If you are wanting to accumulate a list of values that match a condition, there are a few ways.  By far the easiest is to use `filter`, but you can also use explicit recursion.  To use `filter`, you could write your function as

```
lookupOne x list
    = map snd                         -- Return only the values from the assoc list
    $ filter (\y -> fst y == x) list  -- Find each pair whose first element equals x
```

If you wanted to use recursion, you could instead write it as

```
lookupOne _ [] = []                  -- The base case pattern
lookupOne x (y:ys) =                 -- Pattern match with (:), don't have to use head and tail
    if fst y == x                    -- Check if the key and lookup value match
        then snd y : lookupOne x ys  -- If so, prepend it onto the result of looking up the rest of the list
        else         lookupOne x ys  -- Otherwise, just return the result of looking up the rest of the list
```

Both of these are equivalent.  In fact, you can implement `filter` as

```
filter cond [] = []
filter cond (x:xs) =
    if cond x
        then x : filter cond xs
        else     filter cond xs
```

And `map` as

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Hopefully you can spot the similarities between `filter` and `lookupOne`, and with `map` consider `f == snd`, so you have a merger of the two patterns of `map` and `filter` in the explicit recursive version of `lookupOne`.  You could generalize this combined pattern into a higher order function

```
mapFilter :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
mapFilter f cond [] = []
mapFilter f cond (x:xs) =
    if cond x
        then f x : mapFilter f cond xs
        else     : mapFilter f cond xs
```

Which you can use to implement `lookupOne` as

```
lookupOne x list = mapFilter snd (\y -> fst y == x) list
```

Or more simply

```
lookupOne x = mapFilter snd ((== x) . fst)
```

Comment: First I had it with "else" but that wasnt the code taht i want. Because the problem doesn't do what it have to do :D I need it without the "else". if xxx then xxx and than do always yyy. you know what i mean? But you are right. With a "else undefined" there is no error by compiling the code.

Comment: @fuuman Are you wanting to accumulate a list of values to return?  If so, this is not the way to do it.  In Haskell it makes no sense to calculate a value (`snd (head list) : []`), then just throw that value away and compute another value (`lookupOne x (tail list)`).  All expressions return a value, and that value has to be of a static type.

Comment: That's what the code should do: lookupAll [1,2] [(1,"Koblenz"),(1,"Koblenz")] ~?= ["Koblenz","Koblenz"],
    lookupAll [1,1] [(1,"Koblenz")] ~?= ["Koblenz","Koblenz"], And with the else before the lookupOne there is: ### Failure in: LookupAll:1
expected: ["Koblenz","Koblenz"]
 but got: ["Koblenz"]  .... In other languages you can only write if then and there is no need for an else. But the compiler gives me an error, so i need the else here. so i need a cmd that doesn't do anything I think..I am not throughing away the first value. I saved it in the list.After that I recursiv start my function

Comment: Thanks for so much effort every single time I'm coming with my code problems to this site. This website is GREAT! Thanks for all answers, in special to bheklilr for all the explanations! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think @bheklilr is right - you're missing an `else`.

You could fix this particular formatting problem, however, by forming `lookupOne` as a function composition, rather than writing your own new recursive function.

For example, you can get the right kind of behaviour by defining `lookupOne` like this:

```
lookupOne a = map snd . filter ((==) a . fst)
```

This way it's clearer that you're first filtering out the elements of the input list for which the first element of the tuple matches the key, and then extracting just the second element of each tuple.